# Why I can't open site for url like site.com although I give access for index.php in .htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess

I have .htaccess file:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all

# deny view files in directory
Options -Indexes

<FilesMatch "index\.php|profile\.php|newgame\.php|game\.php">
  Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

It works well, I can open `index.php` or `profile.php` for url like `site.com/index.php`. But I can't open site for url `site.com`. Why? I give access to `index.php`. Isn't `site.com` the same of `site.com/index.php`. How to change .htaccess file to take into account this situation?

UPDATE

apache2.conf contains:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure apache to recognize index.php as index file.

Add

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Comment: I change
<IfModule dir_module>
        DirectoryIndex  index.html
</IfModule>

on DirectoryIndex  index.php in httpd.conf. No result, do I right actions?

Comment: place it in your .htaccess, right after the Options -Indexes

Comment: I changed on this:

Order deny,allow
Deny from all

# deny view files in directory
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php

<FilesMatch "index\.php|profile\.php|newgame\.php|game\.php">
  Allow from all
</FilesMatch>

But also access forbidden